# Difference between Shift + F6 and right click run?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have made a java project in netbeans, I have recently seen that there is a UI difference in 2 cases. 1. if i right-click and run the main project or if i press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.
If i do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, a nice user interface (see the buttons), comes up:
[image: Shift+F6]

If i right click on my project and run it; the button style looks ancient:
[image: Right Click and Run]

My question, Why? and 2nd thing; what i want is that if i transfer my program to other systems via JAR files; the nice UI should come. How to do that?

Comment: Refer to [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) docs for the second part of your question.

Comment: Running the project compiles and runs the project with any project properties that may be set while Shift+F6 runs the file without the project properties. The project properties is most likely setting the Look and feel to `CrossPlatformLookAndFeel` (the uglier one) whereas running the file defaults to `SystemLookAndFeel` which gets it's properties from the OS it is running on. To make sure you always gets the prettier look add `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` as the first command in your main method. This is from the link by boxed.

Comment: @ufis I had one more doubt about it, that i love this look and feel (OS: Windows 8); but the thing is that i will be running my program on different OSes like Windows XP too, and even there i want this UI; so is there any way in which i can copy this UI files into my program or something?

Comment: @DakshShah The `SystemLookAndFeel` will get it's properties from the OS. So running on XP will get a look and feel that "looks like XP" which will still not be the ugly `CrossPlatformLookAndFeel`. Creating a pretty look and feel that is the same across multiple platforms is a bit more work. See [The Synth Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) for more info.

Comment: @ufis i think i am new to java and i cant make a UI, right now; so isn't there a way in which i can save the ui along with my program and thus it always shows my UI when if i run it on some other system which does not have that UI, it is not necessary it is this UI but maybe some other good looking UI will also work. (I would try to simplify a bit; like suppose it is html; the buttons are automatic, but i can create a button's image and save in gallery and use every where. So i want something like that - i dont want button as images. But i hope you get my point clearly now...)

Answer (score 0):

When we run the project by clicking "Run", the project is started with the main class file, i.e., with class having main entry point. But when we press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, the file currently open in the editor-window is run using its own main function. So, may be you are doing the same. Probably you have set the Look & Feel of the project in a file other than the file defining your GUI and you are just launching your GUI Frame by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. Thus starting the frame without L&F set.
Just clean and build the project and see the output of the final .jar file.