# Different results when running in Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having a problem, and I can not understand the cause. When I press F6, the project is run and he has an appearance, but when I press Shift + F6 screen has another appearance (which honestly I think prettier). Someone can explain me why the difference? Follow the images of difference.

F6

[image: When I press F6]

Shift + F6

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think the comments in this link may be help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183527/difference-between-shift-f6-and-right-click-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between both is only the look and feel: The first one is the default ("Metal") look and feel, and the second one is the "Nimbus" look and feel.

Without further information given, a guess about the reason: There may be two `main` methods in your project. Maybe one in a "real main class", and one locally in another class that only opens the given chat frame? It might be that in one of the main methods, you are setting the nimbus look and feel (as desrcribed in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html ), and in the other one, you are starting with the default look and feel.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the situation you mentioned, I don't know how I did not notice before. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`F6` Run the main Project and `Shift- F6` Run the file.

So, you probably have some windows initialization on your main project file.